# lexical-level similarity word clustering tool

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, stemming

Is there any open software toolkit that compares the lexcial-level similarities among words and group similar words together? For example, Blue jean, Blue jeans, and blue jea (miss-spelled) should be grouped together? I don't need to look for semantic similarity here.

Answer (score 0):

Try natural language toolkit http://nltk.org/

Here's a rather abstract treatment of the Brown Clustering algorithm http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4705/lectures/brown.pdf

The standard similarity metric between words is the Levenstein distance
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Thanks for answering. And sorry for not being very clear. My question is less about how to calculate the distance between two words, but more about how to choose a cut of value. 
Say I have a list of words,
Blue jeans
Blue jean
Blue
Lucent

How do I decide that blue jeans, blue jean should be grouped together, and blue should be grouped together with lucent, not blue jeans? (apologies for a poor example….)

Comment: @walkman You can use standard clustering algorithms like k-means to do so using the Levenstein distance (a.k.a. edit distance) as John suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you are more interested in **stemming** than in actual clustering e.g. using Levensthein distance: using an unsupervised textual similarity is *way* too likely to produce false positives.

From a lexical similarity point of view,

```
blue jean
blue dean
```

are just one character different, too. Yet, this is a rather unlikely typo.

You really want to use something *supervised* such as porter stemmers to match.